# Oracle Sequential assignment of alphabets based on date column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

Table 1:

```
|Trans|Inc|Date|Status|
-----------------------
|1|1|01/01/2022|null
|5|1|20/01/2022|null
|3|1|03/01/2022|null
|11|2|01/01/2022|null
|3|2|13/12/2021|null
```

result should be

```
|Trans|Inc|Date|Status|
-----------------------
|1|1|01/01/2022|A
|5|1|20/01/2022|C
|3|1|03/01/2022|B
|11|2|01/01/2022|B
|3|2|13/12/2021|A
```

Logic:
Table1 has 4 columns, and status column should be updated on below terms:
1 Inc can have multiple trans attached to it. So status should be updated on the basis Date column. ex. for Inc 1, we have 4 trans(so there will be status A,B,C,D)  and Tran 1 date 01/01/2022 so status is 'A', second record is for inc 1 tran 3, date is 03/01/2022, so the Status is B. Basically we need to assign status alphabetically based on Date column.

Need help for this.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 26 values for an `INC` value?

Comment: Then we should move to 'AA','AB','AC' like wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
SELECT Trans, Inc, Date,
       SUBSTR('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Inc ORDER BY Date), 1) AS Status
FROM yourTable;
```

The trick here is to take a 1-substring of the alphabets depending on the row number position of each record, within each group of company records.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but facing error while updating the existing table as I mentioned the error in other comment. ORA-01427 single query .... while updating the existing table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT Trans,
       Inc,
       "DATE",
       CASE
       WHEN rn < 26      THEN    CHR(65 + rn)
       WHEN rn < 27 * 26 THEN    CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-26)/POWER(26,1)),26))
                              || CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-26)/POWER(26,0)),26))
                         ELSE    CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-27*26)/POWER(26,2)),26))
                              || CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-27*26)/POWER(26,1)),26))
                              || CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-27*26)/POWER(26,0)),26))
       END AS status
FROM   (
  SELECT Trans,
         Inc,
         "DATE",
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Inc ORDER BY "DATE") - 1 AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Trans, Inc, "DATE", Status) AS
SELECT  1, 1, DATE '2022-01-01', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 1, DATE '2022-01-20', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 1, DATE '2022-01-03', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 2, DATE '2022-01-01', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 2, DATE '2021-12-13', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL;
```

This will output statuses from `A` through `Z` then `AA` through to `ZZ` then `AAA` through to `ZZZ` for each `INC` value.

Outputs:

> | TRANS | INC | DATE | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | A |
> | 3 | 1 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | B |
> | 5 | 1 | 2022-01-20 00:00:00 | C |
> | 3 | 2 | 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | A |
> | 11 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | B |

If you want to update the status values then you can `MERGE` using the `ROWID` pseudo-column to correlate:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         CASE
         WHEN rn < 26      THEN    CHR(65 + rn)
         WHEN rn < 27 * 26 THEN    CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-26)/POWER(26,1)),26))
                                || CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-26)/POWER(26,0)),26))
                           ELSE    CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-27*26)/POWER(26,2)),26))
                                || CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-27*26)/POWER(26,1)),26))
                                || CHR(65 + MOD(FLOOR((rn-27*26)/POWER(26,0)),26))
         END AS status
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Inc ORDER BY "DATE") - 1 AS rn
    FROM   table_name t
  )
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET status = src.status;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3c091e9ecedf85e5f9fdf93614c4cb0)*

Comment: update table_name n set status = <your query with only status col in select query and  in where clause where t.inc=n.inc>; is throwing error single row subquery return more than one row. ora-01427

Comment: @OracleForLife Use a `MERGE` statement if you want to update. I've added an example.